# Why does English have a word for pink?

Tags: etymology, adjectives, linguistics

We have a word for light red (pink), but not light blue. Why is this? Russian, for example, has specific words for light and dark blue.

Comment: Why do you assume English does not have words for these colors? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors:_A%E2%80%93F

Comment: [Color terms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_term) vary from language to language. There are generalities, but not the ones you might expect. To quote from the Wikipedia article, "Italian, Russian, and Hebrew have twelve basic color terms, distinguishing blue and azure. That doesn't mean English speakers cannot describe the difference of the two colors, of course; however, in English, _azure_ is not a basic color term because one can say _bright sky blue_ instead, while _pink_ is basic because speakers do not say _light red_."

Comment: Most languages develop enormous number of words for various colors, and then these become mainstream or fall out of use due to various fashions and influences, and rarely map exactly the same colors in other languages. English has quite a few words for various [shades of blue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Shades_of_blue).

Comment: [Piraha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirah%C3%A3_language) doesn't have names for colors, [just calling them what they look like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirah%C3%A3_language#Color_terms): 'blood-like' for red, 'leaf-like' for green, etc.

Comment: RE: _specific words for light and dark blue_: _sky blue_ and _navy_ were the first two terms that sprung to mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

English has names for [light blue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_blue). You just may not know them.  The most common is *cyan*, like the open sky at sea level. Cyan is a very important color because it is one of the three primary colors in the [CMY color model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model).

[image]

English words for light blue include *celeste, cyan, watchet, fesse, pervenche, periwinkle,* and *zircon* — plus others less common. English also has many compound words for light blue, like *robin’s-egg blue, cornflower blue,* and *sky blue*.

English also has many words for dark blue, including *navy, cobalt, indigo,* and *marine*.  Just where *azure* and *cerulean* fall depends who's talking, but they are usually a deeper blue than that of the open sky at sea level, especially one washed out by particulates including pollutants and water vapor.

*Blae* is sometimes a light blue and sometimes a dark one.

---

## In the Pink

[image: pink shades and tints]

Contrary to popular understanding, pink is **not** actually light red. [What most people call pink is really a light magenta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shades_of_magenta), which is [one of the purples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_of_purples) and thus has both red and blue components. And by "light", I presume you mean one of the [pastels: a desaturated color](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastel_(color)).

So *pink* is actually a pastel magenta. **It is not red.** *Rose* is similar.

Comment: Most illuminating. More urgently, how are you at mending Christmas tree lights that are on the blink?

Comment: Terms like "light" and "dark", when applied to colors, generally relate to how a paint of the color would appear if mixed with white or black, respectively, since people interacted with paints long before they had means of interacting directly with different colors of light.  If $800000 is considered "normal" read, then I'd call $FF8080 a "light red" and I'd call $FF0000 "bright red".  While pink is often used to describe colors with more blue than green, I think the main requirements are that red be dominant and saturation be relatively low.